# Error while installing XAMPP on WIndows 7 Home Basic Edition

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, installation, xampp

I recently purchased a Dell Laptop with nice configuration and Windows 7 Home Basic X64 Edition. Now when I am installling the XAMPP, it gives me the following error. Do you know any solution?

[image: Error while installing XAMPP Home Basic Edition]

I searched the net, and tried opening "lusrmgr.msc", but it says that "This computer is running Windows 7 Home Basic. The snapin may not be used with this version."

Comment: Hi. Please note that this is not a programming question and thus does not belong on Stack Overflow. I believe this would be a better match for Super User. -- Finally: How is this message an error? It looks more like a warning, so what exactly is the issue you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type UAC into the start menu or Control Panel search box.
[image]
You can simply drag the slider down, If you drag it all the way down to the bottom **(NEVER Notify)**, you’ll have disabled it entirely.

[image]

Comment: i am getting same error. i think there is some permission issue

Comment: @user1547766 :  restart your windows after you move down the slider to never notify. then try installing xammp

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Xampp setup and click

```
Run as Administrator
```

I think this will serve your purpose.

Comment: @user1547766 It's not an error !!! That is just a notice from XAMPP letting you know that it's recommended not to install it in Program Files. Just put it in C:\xampp and you'll be fine.

Comment: @user1547766 yes its not an error and just a notification. It is received by everyone in case xampp is not being installed directly in the drive but inside program files.